# How to communicate to the window controller from view controller of newly, programmatically created tab?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

In my window controller, I implement:

```
    @IBAction override func newWindowForTab(_ sender: Any?) {
        
        if let wc = NSStoryboard.main?.instantiateInitialController() as? WindowController,
            let window = wc.window {
            
            self.window?.addTabbedWindow(window, ordered: .above)
            window.makeKey()
        }

        
    }
```

In the view controller, I have this code:

`let window = self.view.window?.windowController as? WindowController`

Also tried:

`let window = NSApp.mainWindow?.windowController as? WindowController`

If I don't have any tabs, it's able to get the window controller. But on new tabs, it does grab the window controller.

Similarly, I've unsuccessfully tried sending an action to the WindowController:

`NSApp.sendAction(#selector(WindowController.pageLabelChange), to: nil, from: label)`

Works for the original window, but not for any newly created tabs.

How do the newly created view controller objects communicate with the window controller?

Edit:

For more context in how I am using this code: It's basically a PDFView that's embedded in a window. The window has a tool bar that displays the page number. Using any of the above code, I can set the current page number of the PDFView, but when there's a tab, it does not work. Using the `.PDFViewPageChanged` notification, I call my func

```
NSApp.sendAction(#selector(WindowController.pageLabelChange), to: nil, from: pdfView)
```

Edit 2:

I've created a GitHub with a [test project that shows the problem I have](https://github.com/equivocates/tabtest). You should be able to see that when you launch the project, the `+` button will add a number to the textfield in the tab bar. But if you go to the View menu > Add tab, it creates a new tab, but the `+` does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create new window controller on stack so it is destroyed right after return, that is the reason. You need to store somewhere reference to created tab window controller and manage it (the place of storage is up to your app logic).

Here is simple demo that makes code work

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / macOS 10.15.5

```
final class WindowController: NSWindowController {
    @IBOutlet weak var testField: NSTextField!

    var tabControllers = [WindowController]()  // << storage for child controllers

    @IBAction override func newWindowForTab(_ sender: Any?) {
        if let wc = NSStoryboard.main?.instantiateInitialController() as? WindowController,
            let window = wc.window {
            self.window?.addTabbedWindow(window, ordered: .above)
            window.makeKey()

            tabControllers.append(wc) // keep reference in storage

            // TODO: - you are responsible to manage wc, eg: remove 
            // from storage on window close.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This sort of memory management has been the most difficult part of learning Swift. This solves my problem, but why does the windowcontroller get destroyed right after creation? I understand theres' no strong reference to it, but the window is on screen.

Comment: @TomJ, window and window controller are different objects, the reference to window can be kept in other places - parent window, application, etc.

Comment: @TomJ `NSApplication` keeps a strong reference to a window until it is closed.

Comment: Note to future readers: store `tabControllers` in a global place, don't make it a property of the window controller.